# Linear regression loop in Python (with 3 variables)

Tags: python, loops, regression

I'm attempting to run a linear regression function within a loop with two independent variables and one dependent variable. I've created new objects consisting of 1,000 random numbers selected for each of the 74 data points. I'm able to run this first segment without any issues, but am having trouble when it comes to looping the linear regression function.

```
from sklearn import linear_model

x = glodap_hot_merged_finalized['G2salinity']
y = glodap_hot_merged_finalized['G2talk']
z = glodap_hot_merged_finalized['G2temperature']

iterations = 1000

stdevs = np.empty((iterations,), dtype=float)
slopes = np.empty((iterations,), dtype=float)
intercepts = np.empty((iterations,), dtype=float)

nbot = len(x)
sal = x.values
alk = y.values
temp = z.values
           
sal_ens = np.random.randn(iterations, nbot) * 1e-3 + sal[np.newaxis, :]  
alk_ens = np.random.randn(iterations, nbot) * 2 + alk
temp_ens = np.random.randn(iterations, nbot) * 1e-2 + temp[np.newaxis, :]

# the shapes for sal_ens, alk_ens, and temp_ens are all (1000,74)
```

I've been trying to run the following loop in Python with the sal_ens, temp_ens, and alk_ens variables:

```
for i in range(iterations):

    X = sal_ens[i], temp_ens[i]
    Y = alk_ens[i]
 
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(X, Y)

    intercept_value = sm.add_constant(X) 
    
    intercept =  intercept_value[i]
    coef = regr.coef_[i]
```

I keep getting an error message that says:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2,74]
```

I'm trying to run 1000 regressions using the random numbers selected for each variable (sal_ens, temp_ens, and alk_ens) in order to generate output with 1000 different slopes & intercepts.

Any input or help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve your error, you just need to create your `X` array properly. Currently, your code makes `X` a tuple of two 1-dimensional arrays, each with shape `(74,)`.  If you look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) for the `LinearRegression().fit()` method, you can see that `X` needs to be an array-like object of shape `(n_samples, n_features)`.

So, you can replace that line with this:

```
X = np.hstack((sal_ens[i].reshape(-1,1), temp_ens[i].reshape(-1,1)))
```

The `.reshape(-1,1)` will convert each of the two arrays to a 2-dimensional array of shape `(74,1)` and then `np.hstack(...)` will stack them horizontally to give you your desired array of shape `(74,2)`.

Comment: Thank you! The loop is working, however when I run the code, I receive the following error message: IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2. Is there a way to save each the intercepts and coefficients from all iterations as new objects so that I can apply them to other functions outside of the regression loop?

Comment: @CarolineJ. The `LinearRegression()` class already has a default parameter `fit_intercept=True`, which adds the constant term *before* the model is fit. In your code, your `intercept_value` variable is just a copy of `X` with one more column added (and has nothing to do with the fitted model), so `intercept_value[i]` will just give you a row from that, which is not what you want. You can remove `intercept_value = sm.add_constant(X)` and the next line and replace them with `intercept = regr.intercept_`. Similarly, coefficients should be obtained with `coef = regr.coef_`.

Comment: @CarolineJ. You can append the `intercept` and `coef` values from each iteration to a list, for example.